# oozie 4.1.0 louncher fail with OozieLauncherInputFormat$EmptySplit not found

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

we have upgraded our infrastructure from hdp 2.0 to hdp 2.2 which means upgrade from hadoop 2.2.0 to 2.6.0 and oozie from 4.0.0 to 4.1.0. We are using simple authentication etc. When the job gets submitted oozie launcher is failing with following:

```
2015-02-04 09:56:33,364 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.io.IOException: Split class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.OozieLauncherInputFormat$EmptySplit not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.OozieLauncherInputFormat$EmptySplit not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:361)
    ... 7 more

2015-02-04 09:56:33,373 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task
```

Found that this classes are contained in oozie share/lib uploaded to HDFS to /user/${user.name}/share/lib according to oozie-site.xml configuration:

```
<property>
  <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
  <value>/user/${user.name}/share/lib</value>
</property>
```

where ${user.name} is user under which oozie server is running e.g. oozie. For some reason those libs doesn't get propagated to mapreduce.application.classpath and hence ClassNotFoundException.

Tried to change following property to true:

```
   <property>
    <name>use.system.libpath.for.mapreduce.and.pig.jobs</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

But with no difference. I am not sure what I am missing in installation instruction [here](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/DG_QuickStart.html#Oozie_Share_Lib_Installation)

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thx

UPDATE:
Found that there is a new procedure for installing a sharelibs on oozie 4.1.0 which allows upgrades of libs without restarting the server or waiting for all running jobs to finish. Description can be found [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie-cdh-5/). However I am still facing following issue as command still returns null:

```
[oozie@virtual oozie]$ oozie admin -shareliblist
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hortonworks Hadoop companion files contain oozie-site.xml property oozie.services with missing entry which enables ShareLibService. Which causes that new Shared Lib feature doesn't work as the endpoint is not registered. To fix this add org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService entry to oozie.services list. Be careful as the services are not independent so the order matters!

```
 <property>
      <name>oozie.services</name>
      <value>
      ...
      org.apache.oozie.service.JobsCncurrencyService,
      org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService
 </property>
```

This was the case with HDP 2.2 and clearly was a bug of external configuration files provided separately.
enabled ShareLibService by default !

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the nodes if the class is available in the respected location or not, coz if the class not found exception will come, only if the respected class is not available, or the there are some duplicate Jar is being reade by Oozie on the same time.

You can manually update the Unzip Oozie shared lib folder in the Mention Location with Oozie User, these will work.

Also You need to pass the parament call 
**oozie.use.system.libpath        =   true** , these will inform Oozie to read the same from the DFS shared location, every time, whenever Oozie Stars.

Comment: all of those were verified - none of those were found as a cause of the issue. More over oozie admin -shareliblist doesn't use any of those you mentioned